# Tomorrow it will have been a year since we came..why incorrect?

Tags: grammar, future-perfect

A native speaker (US) told me that this is not right:

> Tomorrow it will have been a year since we came.

I keep wondering why is that? Is it not expressing that by that time (tomorrow) it will have been a year..., i.e. expressing that something will have finished, in this case "being for less than 10" years?

At the same time, this was considered correct:

> Tomorrow we will have lived here for a year.

Comment: I think the original sentence is fine.

Comment: Perhaps they were looking for a comma between *Tomorrow* and *it*. Or they might prefer *will be* to *will have been* with respect to a future date. The original sentence doesn't look too bad, really. In any case, the speaker would be in a much better position than we are to say why they didn't like your original sentence.

Comment: Well, I was told that the future perfect here is not correct, in the first sentence.

Comment: You were told incorrectly. It’s fine. It’s a bit clunky, perhaps, but perfectly grammatical, and not unlikely to be heard in actual conversation.

Comment: Not all "*native speaker[s] (US)*" know what they're talking about. Take it from one native speaker (US). ;-)

Comment: @Drew same. I make mistakes all the time, as a native speaker. But, I will agree that there are better ways to express the above than the first example (such as the second example).

Comment: I think what makes the first sentence incorrect in my eyes might be the fact that the destination is not defined, in the sense that the thought could be incomplete. (Came to where? Home? A party? Over? Someplace else?). Second sentence defines here (wherever here is) as a location. But, again, this is an opinion.

Comment: *Today, it has been a year since we came.* Fine. So shifting into the future, we get *Tomorrow, it will have been a year since we came.* Also fine.

Comment: You native English speakers are OK with '..since we came'? It sounds very stilted, really needs a time objective '... since we came the first time'. Yes, it is intransitive but seems to feel ... progressive? that is, '...since we arrived' 
 is perfectly OK. Forgetting grammar, 'came' just sounds off.

Comment: @psosuna: FWIW, I have no problem with either sentence.

Comment: @Mitch: yes, *since we came here* would be better. But to me, *since we came* is certainly acceptable.

Comment: @PeterShor this would be what would solve my dilemma of lack of direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 'Tomorrow, it will have been a year since we came.'

A future event with the future perfect tense is correct.

> Or, 'Tomorrow, we will have lived here a year.'

When something occurs in the future and a retrospective significance is attached to it, the future perfect simple is also appropriate.

Comment: But the point is - why not future perfect with the first sentence (..will have been a year).

Comment: @user970696 I think I have that covered now. Finger trouble in first post.

Comment: Technically, 'Tomorrow, it be a year since we came' would also be usable in certain parts of the UK (Yorkshire, particularly) but I did not want to post that as it involves arguments about whether we actually _have_  a future tense  in English.

Comment: You _have_ posted 'Tomorrow, it will be a year since we came.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have just edited that out. Trying to give too much information, again.